Change of Capacitance due to insertion of dielectric
I was going through Griffiths, Introduction to Electrodynamics and found myself hanging on the Electric Field in Matter chapter. To give a bit of context, I am familiar with dielectrics in the past but it wasn't rigorous enough. I'll jump straight onto the question. Here is the Scenario, Consider two infinite plates separated by a distance d(Same as saying keeping 2 plates very close, at least mathematically). Now using the Equation
$$\nabla\cdot\textbf{D}=\rho_f$$
Where $\rho_f$ stands for Free Charge density(Not due to polarization). Since I am assuming that there is no Free-charge density between the plates i.e. $\rho_f=0$.
$$\nabla\cdot\textbf{D}=0$$
Which gives the solution
$$\textbf{D}=\textbf{c}$$
Where $\textbf{c}$ is a constant. We also assume Linear Dielectrics and we can use the relation
$$\textbf{P}=\epsilon_0\chi_e\textbf{E}$$
and
$$\epsilon=\epsilon_0(1+\chi_e)$$
Then
$$\textbf{D}=\epsilon\textbf{E}$$
$$\textbf{E}=\frac{\textbf{c}}{\epsilon}$$
Now I got stuck. I don't have any idea how to proceed. I wanted to prove the change in Capacitance. Without it, I cannot proceed forward. It will be really helpful if you guys can help with how to determine $\textbf{c}$. Thanks in advance.

What does the symbol between $\epsilon_o$ and $E$ mean?

@BobD That is the electric susceptibility

$c$ in your last equation is the charge density $\sigma$ on the capacitor plates, where $\sigma=\frac{Q}{A}$. Increasing the permittivity $\epsilon$ by insertion of a dielectric decreases the effective electric field between the plates.
You can arrive at the same conclusion from the following:
The capacitance is given by
$$C=\frac{A\epsilon}{d}\tag{1}$$
The relationship between capacitance, charge and voltage is
$$C=\frac{Q}{V}\tag{2}$$
Substituting (2) into (1)
$$\frac{Q}{V}=\frac{A\epsilon}{d}$$
$$V=\frac{Qd}{A\epsilon}$$
Then since $E=\frac{V}{d}$
$$E=\frac{Q}{A\epsilon}$$
And since
$$\sigma=\frac{Q}{A}$$
We obtain
$$E=\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon}$$
Hope this helps.

My question was regarding, how you derive the capacitance formula. I know how to derive it in free space, but can you prove that the above formula is valid in general(I'm asking to prove it)? It will be really helpful if you can.

@Charu_Bamble you wanted to derive my eq (1) starting with your first equation? Because that wasn’t clear.

Yeah, I'm sorry for the lack of clarification.

Capacitance is capacity to hold charge at fixed voltage (well, that is one way to state it).
The voltage only cares about electric field, so the voltage between the plates (at fixed free charge on the plates) is (up to sign):
$$ V=\int_{x=0}^{x=d}E(x)dx = Ed $$
so when you insert the dielectric, $E$ goes down, hence $V$ goes down, and:
$$ C = \frac Q V $$
goes up.
